# How to access table in another database in T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can access tables in another database OK using the fully qualified name like

```
select * from [DEV-test].dbo.ArchiveCutoff
```

Now I want to do the same table in a stored procedure.

My code is

```
create procedure test  
    @src varchar (128) 
as
begin
  set @src = '[DEV-test]'
  select * from  @src.dbo.ArchiveCutoff
end
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

What is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Do you want to change the source database depending on some criteria in stored procedure?

Comment: You **cannot** replace the database, table or column names with parameters. If you want to do this, you'll have to resort to "dynamic SQL"

Comment: Sorry I did not put the paragraph right as it is my first time on this site. It should be

Comment: @GeorgeLu:- Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for Dynamic SQL, using one of [the textbook examples](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_DB).  This is generally a bad idea, though there are workarounds.  If you read the linked article, some suggestions are offered.

If you absolutely have to use it, though, you are looking for

```
create procedure test  @src varchar (128) as
begin

 set @src = QUOTENAME(@src) -- leave this 
 set @src = '[DEV-test]'

 declare @sql varchar(200)
 set @Sql = 'select * from ' + @src + '.dbo.ArchiveCutoff'

 EXEC (@SQL)


end
```

or

```
create procedure test  @src varchar (128) as
begin

 set @src = QUOTENAME(@src) -- leave this 
 set @src = '[DEV-test]'


 EXEC ('select * from ' + @src + '.dbo.ArchiveCutoff')


end
```

Comment: @R.T., it isn't different: my code is basically the same.  I began writing this answer before yours was posted, and I didn't see yours until after I already posted it:  no piracy was intended.  Once I had posted my answer I saw your own, very similar answer, but decided to leave mine up because of the link.

Comment: These are all helpful. Thanks. I am really impressed in the quick response.

Comment: You need to wrap your database name variable in QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection. As posted this is wide open.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline query

```
create procedure test 
( @src varchar (128) )as
begin
 set @src = '[DEV-test]'
 declare @x varchar(100)
 @x = 'select * from' +  @src +'.dbo.ArchiveCutoff'
 exec(@x)
end
```

Comment: @George Lu:- You may accept the answer if that helped you! :) A right tick mark near the upvote option(it will turn green)

Comment: You need to wrap your database name variable in QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection. As posted this is wide open.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a modification to the previous two answers. I realize in your code you pass in a parameter and then set it to a hardcoded value. I assume that is for testing purposes. The problem is that both of the posted solutions are vulnerable to sql injection once you remove that line. A minor change to both of the excellent previous answers might be like this to prevent sql injection.

```
create procedure test 
( 
    @src varchar (128) 
)as
    --Presumably this line will be removed after testing. 
    --And because we are using QUOTENAME you want the actual name here with no brackets.
    set @src = 'DEV-test' 

    set @src = QUOTENAME(@src) --This is to help prevent sql injection
    declare @x nvarchar(100)
    set @x = N'select * from ' +  @src +'.dbo.ArchiveCutoff'
    --uncomment the exec line when comfortable your code is correct
    --exec sp_executesql @x

    select @x
GO
```